# ASP button with Parameter to Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, parameters

I have a page status.aspx that contains several buttons such as 30 days, 60 days & 90 days. I would like to pass the parameters to my existing gridview depending on which button has been clicked. My code behide for the gridview as follows:

```
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("up_AcctStatus", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim paramNumOfDays As New SqlParameter("@NumOfDays", SqlDbType.Int)
    paramNumOfDays.Value = "??? 30, 60 or 90 ???"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramNumOfDays)
```

GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        GridView1.DataBind()

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: How do I pass the parameters from status.aspx button to the gridview parameter?

Comment: Is answer with C# code welcome?

Comment: VB would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any ORM but sqlComand you can:

```
            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Fill(60);
            }
            protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Fill(30);
            }

            private void Fill(int numberOfDays)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("stored procedure name", connection);
                    sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDays", numberOfDays);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sda.Fill(ds, "result_table");

                    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["result_table"];
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

vb:

```
                Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                Fill(60)
                End Sub

                Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                    Fill(30)
                End Sub

                Private Sub Fill(numberOfDays As Integer)
                    Using connection As New SqlConnection("connectionString")
                        connection.Open()

                        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                        sda.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("stored procedure name", connection)
                        sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDays", numberOfDays)

                        Dim ds As New DataSet()
                        sda.Fill(ds, "result_table")

                        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("result_table")
                         GridView1.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Sub
```

Comment: The VB code works if the gridview1 was on the same page as the buttons page status.aspx, but the gridview1 is on a different page called view.aspx. I need to pass the 60 or 30 to that page. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe I could do a Response.Redirect("view.aspx") with parameters.

Comment: or you can store parameter (int = 30 or 60) into a Session. And on Page Load of page with Grid 'take it' from Session and execute Fill(parametrFromSession)

Comment: Perfect. Will give that shot.

Comment: ok :) so You know. hehe I'm happy to get my first points on stackoverflow :) Now I won't be only a 'leecher' ;)

Comment: It worked. I stored the number of days in a session for each button. Session("NumOfDays") = 30. Did a Response.Redirect("view.aspx") and got the gridview parameter from the session. Are there draw backs on using session? When should I terminate it?

Comment: Session TimeOuts automatically after time configured for your ASP.Net web application. If you don't know about your Session settings you can also use different approach: you said you do Response.Redirect("view.aspx"). Try doing Response.Redirect("view.aspx?days=30"). And on Page Load take the Parameter from QueryStrig. So for e.g  int days = Request.Querystring["days"]. And then Fill(days). But you must take into consideration that if user will see the url and parameter he could manipulate it. So you need validation of parameter at page load (accept only 30,60,90 in query string)